# What data type should I use to parse sizes in /proc/[pid]/smaps?

Tags: c, linux

Are they always times of 4kB?
How big could it be to sum up all `Sizes` in smaps?

Answer (score 1):

The granularity there is the memory page size. It may be or 4096 or 8192 bytes (or even something else, not sure). Typically you may determine it with `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)` or use predefined `PAGE_SIZE` macro if available.

And the upper limit for the sum of all `Size` entries is the overall virtual address space size, i.e. `2^32` bytes for 32-bit system and `2^64` bytes for 64-bit ones.
Of course real cases will always be under this limit at least because kernel occupies some part of address space and it is not reported in `/proc/<pid>/smaps`.

Answer (score 1):

**smaps** contains memory pages that are used by process, as described in **proc** man page:

[man 5 proc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

So the total size of Rss blocks is not larger than the RAM of the host.
The total size of virtual memory is limited by the CPU data bus size. But on 64-bit CPU not all 64 lines are used so the actual size of addressable space can be obtained from **cpuinfo**:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'address'
```

which outputs something like

```
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
```

where 'physical' is the supported physical RAM size and 'virtual' is the maximum bits that are used for addressing virtual memory. So 2^48 is the maximum addressable space for the CPU and the maximum sum of virtual memory for any process.

The sizes are times of RAM page size.

RAM page size can be checked with

```
getconf PAGESIZE
```

and is usually 4096.